# Can a sorcerer use metamagic when casting a spell via a spell scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, sorcerer, metamagic

Can a sorcerer use metamagic when casting a spell via a spell scroll?

Comment: Related: [Can you cast a quickened spell into a ring of spell storing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105175/can-you-cast-a-quickened-spell-into-a-ring-of-spell-storing/105176#105176).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Yes.

From [scrolls](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll#content):

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and **cast its spell** without providing any material Components. **Casting the spell** by reading the scroll requires the spell’s normal Casting Time. If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your Spellcasting ability to determine whether **you cast it** successfully.

So, clearly, you are casting the spell from its scroll.

Reading [Metamagic](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#toc_9) options, you have only 2 conditions:

> Almost all options: When you **cast a spell** ...
>
> Empowered Spell: When you **roll damage** for a spell...

So yes, you can use your MetaMagic features when casting a spell from a scroll.

JC also backs this up with [this tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/05/10/sorcerers-cant-use-metamagics-with-spells-from-staff-of-power-correct/) (thanks to [Slagmoth](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/29513/slagmoth) for finding it):

> If a magic item's description says you cast a spell from it, you can use Metamagic on the spell.

Comment: So a Sorcerer 5/ druid 1 could purchase a scroll of awaken and cast it on two creatures or plants?

Comment: @JosiahRiggan I'm not sure what scroll that is, but if Twinned Spell is available, Awakening matches its criteria, and belongs to either Sorcerer or Druid classes, then yes